# to check if another application instance is running and bring that instance in focus

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Presently when I click twice on app icon 2 instances are started.

Is there any way that on starting my 'A' GUI application, it directs me to existing running application instead of startng a new instance of 'A'?

Answer (score 0):

Try something on the following lines:

```
if root.state()=='running':
    root.lift()
```

This should raise your root window to the top or any toplevel window, if you so desire.

Comment: This only addresses half of the problem. The question is mainly about how to detect if a program is already running.

Comment: exactly my thoughts